# Bad Request reponse Guzzle para Google Storage no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, google-storage

Bom dia, estou com um problema ao enviar um arquivo para o Google Storage ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Client error: `SETURI http://dev-site.com.br/storage` resulted in a
>   `400 Bad Request` response

Meu código de envio está assim:

```
if ($request->hasfile('path')) {

            $token = 'Codigodotoken';

            $guzzleHttpService = new GuzzleHttpClient();

            $guzzleHttpService->setUri(env('URI_API_STORAGE_SS'));
            $response = $guzzleHttpService
            ->setPath(self::PATH_STORAGE)
            ->send('post', [
                'headers' => ['Authorization' => $token],
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'file',
                        'contents' => fopen($request->file->getPathName(), 'r'),
                        'path' => $request->file->getClientOriginalName()
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'permission_id',
                        'contents' => 1
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'status_id',
                        'contents' => 2
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'type_file_id',
                        'contents' => 6
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'user_id',
                        'contents' => $file->getUserId()
                    ],
                ]
            ]);

            dd($response);
```

Não estou conseguindo identificar se o problema está na requisição ou no modo que estou tentando enviar o arquivo.

Comment: O "contents" do "file" recebe mesmo uma *stream* para o arquivo ou deveria receber o conteúdo do mesmo?

Comment: Ela realmente recebe uma stream, pelo menos o modelo que me passaram que estavam usando é desta maneira mesmo, o que não me foi passado foi como eu capturar este arquivo, não sei se o meu foreach foi a maneira correta de fazer isso no laravel, possuo pouca experiencia com o framework

Comment: Eu recomendaria fazer essa requisição no Postman ou softwares alternativos para saber exatamente qual é a requisição que precisa fazer, depois migre-a para o Guzzle.

Comment: Consegui verificar no postman e realmente é o arquivo mesmo,`$request->file`, porém ainda persiste o erro de bad request, pelo menos sei que o problema não é em meu arquivo, enviando o post pelo Postman ele envia e me retorna corretamente, porém pela minha aplicação retorna o erro

Comment: Da uma relida na doc, pelo que me lembro está faltando informações, da uma relida na doc.